# Unable to define a custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

Using:

1. Keras 2.1.5
2. ipython 6.2.1
3. ipython_genutils 0.2.0
4. Python 3
5. Windows 7(x64) - 8GB ram - only CPU

I am trying to make a neural network on jupyter notebook and it was working fine until I decided to code a custom loss function. For a starter, I decided to code a simple mean square loss function. 
The loss function is:

```
def msqeloss(y_true, y_pred):
     return K.sum(K.square(y_true-y_pred),0)
```

And I input this function into the model as:

```
...
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(120,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',loss=msqeloss,metrics=['accuracy'])
...
```

The full-stack error comes out to be this:

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-86f0a38b9a14> in <module>()
     42         model.add(Dropout(0.1))
     43         model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
---> 44         model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',loss=msqeloss,metrics=['accuracy'])
     45         csv_logger = CSVLogger('meanlog_loss_log'+str(index)+'.csv', append=True, separator=';')
     46         model.fit(Xtrain,one_hot_labels,batch_size=10,epochs=Epochs,validation_data=(Xtest,np_utils.to_categorical(ytest, num_classes=3)),callbacks=[csv_logger])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    822                            weighted_metrics=weighted_metrics,
    823                            target_tensors=target_tensors,
--> 824                            **kwargs)
    825         self.optimizer = self.model.optimizer
    826         self.loss = self.model.loss

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    828                 with K.name_scope(self.output_names[i] + '_loss'):
    829                     output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
--> 830                                                 sample_weight, mask)
    831                 if len(self.outputs) > 1:
    832                     self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    427         """
    428         # score_array has ndim >= 2
--> 429         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
    430         if mask is not None:
    431             # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in Theano

<ipython-input-9-d8157a575c41> in msqeloss(y_true, y_pred)
      1 def msqeloss(y_true, y_pred):
----> 2     return K.sum(K.square(y_true-y_pred),0)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

I am pretty new to Keras and any help would be highly appreciated. Please, help me out on this one since it has been bothering me for 2 days now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you defined `K`?

Comment: Yes, as @Kapil mentioned, it seems like somewhere in your code, you redefined `K` from `keras.backend` to an `int` variable...

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I feel so dumb right now for even asking this here. Much appreciated!